# Targeting a <p> and converting it into an array

Tags: javascript

I would like to target all the `<p>` and convert it into an array. I have tried spread operator, `Array.from` or by using methods like `.split()` or `.splice()`. But it seems that the problem is to find the right target and understand how to operate with Element object-text which I have not yet...

```js
const targetDates = document.querySelector('.data');
console.log(targetDates.childNodes.entries)
```

```html
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="dates" class="data">
            1429
    1368
    1661
    1687
    1593
    1495
    1565
    1500
    1635
        </p>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  const targetDates = document.querySelector('.data');
  const textData=targetDates.childNodes[0].textContent;
  const finalTextData=textData.trim().split('\n');//using trim() because the of the first blank space
  
  const newValue=finalTextData.map(item=>item.trim())
```

So with the `.textcontent` you can access to the content of `<p>` then you have to remove the blank space at first via `trim()` and split them base of `'\n'` which is `Enter`.Although you can find some `RegExp` to solve the problem ,you can also solve this issue with this steps

Answer (score 1):

That element has a single child node, which is a text node.

```js
const p = document.querySelector('#dates');
console.log(p.childNodes.length);
```

```html
        <p id="dates" class="data">
            1429
    1368
    1661
    1687
    1593
    1495
    1565
    1500
    1635
        </p>
```

In such a case, it's usually easiest to use `.textContent` to retrieve only the text inside the element, and then you can manipulate the text to process the numbers as you like - such as splitting by newlines, or by matching numbers in the string with a regular expression:

```js
const p = document.querySelector('#dates');
const nums = p.textContent.match(/\d+/g);
for (const num of nums)  {
  console.log(num);
}
```

```html
<p id="dates" class="data">
            1429
    1368
    1661
    1687
    1593
    1495
    1565
    1500
    1635
        </p>
```